# Retrieve binding info after mapping

Tags: sapui5

I have a button in xml-view

```
<Button text="{ABCDE}" press="onPress" >
```

If I press it I can manage the action by the function

```
onPress: function (evt) {
    ...
}
```

In this function can I retrieve the string "ABCDE" (starting from `evt`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a loog at `evt.getSource().getBindingContext()`, this should hold all the information you need. Then you can get the bound Path by calling `getPath()` and the value with `getProperty()`.

Comment: In my case I have a table http://jsbin.com/fulitojeni/1/edit and I get a list of binding infos by http://jsbin.com/doxodomelu/1/edit?js